# Optimising a code block into a loop

Tags: c++, performance, loops, optimization

I am pretty new to C++ and compiled languages in general I have a strong interpreted background so I am trying to get my head around the limitations of not having access to certain things at compile time.

At present I have a large block of code which looks like this:

```
//New note, note36

MemoryInputStream* input36 = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::C1hard1_wav, BinaryData::C1hard1_wavSize, false);
auto reader36 = audioFormatManager.createReaderFor(input36);

BigInteger note36;
note36.setRange(36, 1, true);

addSound(new SamplerSound("note36", *reader36, note36, 36, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));

delete input36;
delete reader36;

//New note, note37

MemoryInputStream* input37 = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::Csharp1hard1_wav, BinaryData::Csharp1hard1_wavSize, false);
auto reader37 = audioFormatManager.createReaderFor(input37);

BigInteger note37;
note37.setRange(37, 1, true);

addSound(new SamplerSound("note37", *reader37, note37, 37, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));

delete input37;
delete reader37;
```

This code repeats 48 times in this method and this is not good practice. An example of how I would achieve this in PHP, an interpreted language would look something like this

```
$noteMap = array(36 => "C1", 37 => "Csharp1");

foreach($noteMap as $midiNumber => $note)
{
    $name = $note . "hard1_wav";
    $size = $note . "hard1_wavSize";

    $input = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::$name, BinaryData::$size, false);
    $reader = audioFormatManager->createReaderFor($input);

    //I know this bit is bad PHP, no bigintegers in PHP but I can't think of a way to replicate it for arguments sake
    $note = 0;
    $note->setRange($midiNumber, 1, true);

    addSound(new SamplerSound("note".$midiNumber, $reader36, $note, $midiNumber, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));
}
```

This is much more manageable and reusable. Changes I make will not need to be carefully repeated throughout the file and changes can be made quickly. I know that passing variables as function names is not something that be done in compiled languages, but even taking that into account there must be a way to wrap my large code block into a neat loop I just can't find the resource out there explaining it to me.

Comment: You can't do that in c++. Variable names won't be modifiable at runtime. Use a `std::vector` or another container for the readers and midi channels and loop over that one instead.

Comment: In C++ you can use a `std::map` for the map, and a range based `for` for the `foreach`. And you don't have to use inefficient dynamic allocation for the `input` or the `reader`.

Comment: @user0042: His code doesn't require run time variable names.

Comment: Your C++ code and PHP should be a pretty straight conversion.  What does  `$noteMap = array(36 => "C1", 37 => "Csharp1");` do?

Comment: @NathanOliver it is just setting values in an array to strings, those strings reflect the method names of the BinaryData class. In PHP you can call a method or even a variable with a variable. It is specifically the addSound(...) function call in the loop where I am coming unstuck I can't figure out in c++ how to dynamically call those methods

Comment: From the type names this looks like code for the JUCE framework. I don't know a lot about that, but it looks like instead of using `BinaryData::name` you can try using the function `BinaryData::getNamedResource`, which takes a name as a null-terminated string and and a reference to a size. It returns the data and fills in the size. This way you can reference BinaryData by strings rather than using the dynamic variable names you're trying to use.

Comment: @Richie If you want to use a string as a function name then this is where function pointers (or functors/lambda) come into play.  You create a `std::map` where each string maps to a specific function (this will be the long part) and then you can access the map with a string and get the corresponding function to run.  You are correct that C++ doesn't have that PHP feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming BinaryData is a JUCE generated resource file the following algorithm should be equivalent to your PHP version. This doesn't use dynamic variable names, instead it uses the `BinaryData::getNamedResource` function that should appear in the [JUCE generated code](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/blob/90bbda1f195b4cf940f54f7f41986e0d5d68c9ec/extras/Projucer/Source/Project%20Saving/jucer_ResourceFile.cpp#L149).

```
std::map<int, std::string> note_map{{36, "C1"}, {37, "Csharp1"}};
for ( const auto& note : note_map ) {
    BigInteger midi_bit;
    midi_bit.setBit(note.first);

    int size;
    std::string note_resource = note.second + "hard1_wav";
    auto data = BinaryData::getNamedResource(note_resource.c_str(), size);

    auto input = new MemoryInputStream(data, size, false);
    auto reader = audioFormatManager->createReaderFor(input);

    auto note_name = "note" + std::to_string(note.first);
    addSound(new SamplerSound(note_name.c_str(), *reader, midi_bit,
                              note.first, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));
}
```

Another (bad) solution is to use the C Preprocessor to generate the code something like the following:

```
#define note(num, name)                                                                                               \
    MemoryInputStream* input##num = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::name##_wav, BinaryData::name##_wavSize, false); \
    auto reader##num = audioFormatManager.createReaderFor(input##num);                                                \
    BigInteger note##num;                                                                                             \
    note##num.setBit(num);                                                                                            \
    addSound(new SamplerSound("note" #num, *reader##num, note##num, num, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));                         \
    delete input##num;                                                                                                \
    delete reader##num
note(36, C1);
note(37, Csharp1);
```

The following code is generated by the preprocessing stage:

```
MemoryInputStream* input36 = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::C1_wav, BinaryData::C1_wavSize, false); auto reader36 = audioFormatManager.createReaderFor(input36); BigInteger note36; note36.setBit(36); addSound(new SamplerSound("note" "36", *reader36, note36, 36, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0)); delete input36; delete reader36;
MemoryInputStream* input37 = new MemoryInputStream(BinaryData::Csharp1_wav, BinaryData::Csharp1_wavSize, false); auto reader37 = audioFormatManager.createReaderFor(input37); BigInteger note37; note37.setBit(37); addSound(new SamplerSound("note" "37", *reader37, note37, 37, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0)); delete input37; delete reader37;
```

The preprocessor solution should be code equivalent to your current solution, but in general it is not very good practice to generate tons of variables using macros in this way. The runtime solution above should be preferred over using the preprocessor.

Comment: Well spotted on it being JUCE Framework code. I didn't think there was a JUCE specific answer so I didn't mention it in my original question. Your answer seems to be around what I need, however in its current form it is causing my host application to crash even though it compiles nicely!

Comment: I think it's because I forgot the "_wav" part of the note names. I'll edit my answer to try to include that. You can `#include <cassert>` and use `assert(data)` to make sure that the pointer returned by `getNamedResource` is not `nullptr`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the way JUCE performs memory management. You may need to `delete` the items created with `new` in the loop if JUCE does not assume ownership of the memory. I did not include the `delete` statements in the loop, but they're in your original code.

Comment: Yep that has fixed it and thanks for the pointer, I'm still getting to grips with the nuances of C++ and compiled languages in general.

Comment: I will need to either declare them with RAII or delete them myself JUCE doesn't handle that it will be leaking right now, but it works. Worth mentioning that you left in php method call syntax on the audioFormatReader so I had to change that to C++ syntax. Thanks though!

Comment: Does the reader assume ownership of the stream? It doesn't in the OP's code. Sounds like a leak here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it does not

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
typedef void (FuncPtr)(int x);
void C1Func(int x);
void CSharpFunc( int x);

void someFunc() {
    const Input input = new MemoryInputStream(name, size, false);
    const Reader reader = audioFormatManager->createReaderFor(input);

    // note: gxx syntax here, may not be supported in other versions...    
    Note noteMap[48] = { [36]=Note(36,C1Func), [37]=Note(37,CSharpFunc) };
    String name, size;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySizeOf(noteMap); i++) {
        Note * note = noteMap[i];
        if (!note->isInitialized())
             continue;
        name = note + "hard1_wav";
        size = note + "hard1_wavSize";
        note->setRange(i,1,true);
        std::string name = "note"+i;
        addSound(new SamplerSound(name, reader, note[i], i, 0.001, 0.01, 26.0));
    }
    delete input;
    delete reader;
}
```

You'll need a `Note` class with a constructor (`Note::Note(int idx,FuncPtr fn)`).   Also the initialization of the array is specific to gnu, so you might need to use `std::map` or something equivalent instead, (or define `INVALID_NOTE` as invalid and add a bunch of `INVALID_NOTE,`'s in there to mark the other array members as empty).

Answer (score 0):

Don't that, such a waste of resources, where you call new and delete on every Note.

Use a data structure instead, such as an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or an [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Once you fill your data structure you can iterate over its elements.

Comment: It's just an array, there is no data in those values only strings. Those strings are then interpreted as method names which I believe is something that is entirely impossible in C++ so I'm not sure what the solution is here